# Jquery click on button after the lightbox closed

Tags: jquery, lightbox

I try to click a button after thelightbox is closed like :

```
jQuery(document).on("click", ".pp_overlay", function() {
  $(".con-playpause:first").click();
});
```

but i cant make it work 
Thanks for your help

Comment: Depending on how the event is handled, and what type of element `.con-playpause` actually is, you may need to raise a native `click` event, eg `$(".con-playpause")[0].click()`. It would help to see your HTML here to give a definitive solution

Comment: i want the music player to stop when the lightbox open that i manage to make it work but restart when the lightbox is closed  that i cant find how to make it happen :) Thanks again<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
 $('.iconOver').click(function() {
 $(".con-playpause:first").click();
 });
});
</script>

<script>
jQuery(document).on("click", ".pp_overlay", function() {
    
$(".con-playpause")[0].click()
 
});
</script>

Comment: In that case you'd be best to call `play()` and `pause()` directly on the `audio` element instead of faking click events on elements which may/may not have event listeners attached

Comment: ok super thank you .. play and pause  great can you show me how to target the audio element ?

Comment: The same as any other element, `$('#yourAudioElement')`

Comment: Thank you for your help